Ubuntu 24.04 - could not connect bluetooth mouse and keyboard
After updating from 22.04 to 24.04, I have a problem connecting my devices. They do not appear during the search.
sudo hcitool scan
bluetoothctl: scan on
show nothing. Device successfully paired to Android Phone and Windows.
Logitech MX Keys + Logitech M720
~$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-10-20 13:01:57 CEST; 9min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1419 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 57141)
     Memory: 3.6M (peak: 4.5M)
        CPU: 118ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1419 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

bluetoothd[1419]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.165 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_1
bluetoothd[1419]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.165 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_0
bluetoothd[1419]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.165 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_1
bluetoothd[1419]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.165 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx_ll_duplex_0
bluetoothd[1419]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.165 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream
bluetoothd[1419]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.165 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/faststream_duplex
bluetoothd[1419]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.165 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05
bluetoothd[1419]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.165 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05
bluetoothd[1419]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.165 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/opus_05_duplex
bluetoothd[1419]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.165 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/opus_05_duplex

rfkill list bluetooth
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

~$ lsusb | grep -i bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:4853 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio

~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    2.374420] usb 3-10: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[   76.275933] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   76.275958] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   76.275959] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   76.275962] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   76.275965] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   76.275969] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   76.293172] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0b hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0b lmp_subver=8852
[   76.294168] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[   76.294174] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8852bu_fw.bin
[   76.295374] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8852bu_config.bin
[   76.295800] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 6, total sz 58003
[   76.593188] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0xdbc6b20f
[   76.677164] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP extensions version v1.00
[   76.677169] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP quality report is supported
[   77.278065] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   77.278069] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   77.278075] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   77.279337] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[   79.891909] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   79.891919] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   79.891925] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  360.082396] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0b hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0b lmp_subver=8852
[  360.083413] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[  360.083437] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8852bu_fw.bin
[  360.084271] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8852bu_config.bin
[  360.084410] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 6, total sz 58003
[  360.384585] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0xdbc6b20f
[  360.475254] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP extensions version v1.00
[  360.475280] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP quality report is supported
[  360.475572] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[  563.831338] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP extensions version v1.00
[  563.831354] Bluetooth: hci0: AOSP quality report is supported


The problem was with power management. When the power supply was low system disables Bluetooth.
